# Understanding browser plugins: creation, deployment, and use

Tags: javascript, plugins, cross-browser, digital-certificate

Let's say I wanted to create a browser plug-in that would open someone's floppy drive for them whenever they click a button on my web page.  (You remember that old gag? - Don't worry, I don't really want to do that.)

- What are the steps necessary to create a browser plug-in that will work on most browsers and most operating systems?
- How do I deploy the plug-in?  For instance, how do I make it so that the plug-in can be easily downloaded and installed?  Do I have to worry about digital certificates?
- How do I check for and use the pluggin once it's installed?  Is it available to javascript in the form of an API?

Comment: You want to create a browser plugin that works on most browsers? Nay..

Comment: I think he's referring to a plugin (like flash player), not a plugin or extension, which indeed have differente APIs.

Comment: I thought that on SO down votes were always associated with comments.

Comment: drive-by downvoters are the scourge of SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at a project called FireBreath: http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home

Firebreath abstracts many of the differences between the browser plugin frameworks and platform issues so you can easily write the code for a plugin once and just re-compile it for different platforms.

I have found it good for exposing existing C/C++ library API's to Javascript so I can write dynamic pages that use functionality from the C++ library which were otherwsie not available.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers have their own plugin frameworks for developers to utilize. So, for example, a Firefox plugin will not work in chrome or IE. Firefox and chrome do both utilize javascript and css but they are fundamentally different in their structure.

As far as deployment, Mozilla and Google provide hosting for their respective plugins. I do know that firefox extensions are basically zip files with the extension changed.

EDIT...

I had assumed you meant browser extensions so disregard my answer if that is not the case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between browser plug-ins and browser extensions.

Comment: Well, I personally use the terms interchangeably. By extension/plug-in I was referring to an application designed to integrate with and extend the functionality of a web browser. FireBug is a popular extension for firefox used by developers for debugging html/css/javascript, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest cross-browser solution is use Java Applets or maybe Flash (I am not sure how you do it in Flash).

With applets, you would need to sign the applet and also create a security policy file for accessing the disk. When the applet loads in the browser it would ask permission from the client user, he/she needs to click Allow to give permission for the applet to access the disk. This would allow you to access any disk in the system.